# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<any>'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following code:

```
this.afDb.list('/demo').push({a: 'b'})
    .then(_ => console.log('works'))
    .catch(err => console.log('err: ', err));
```

I get the following error on 'catch':

```
[ts] Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<any>'.
```

Seems like a AngularFire2 bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is reported because the `PromiseLike` interface in typescript lacks a `catch` method. This is consistent with the definition of a "thenable" as an object with a `then` method.

```
interface PromiseLike {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike) | undefined | null): PromiseLike;
}
```

is how it's defined in [lib.es2015.promise.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts) on gitHub, starting at line 1291. (The linked HTML page is 5.5MB in size - it may take a while.)

Bear in mind too that the [A5+ spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) doesn't mention a `catch` method, and ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) promises provide `catch` as a `Promise.prototype` function that simply calls `then` with the first argument of `catch` as the second argument of `then`.

The easiest solution may be to use a two parameter `then` call:

```
this.afDb.list('/demo').push({a: 'b'})
    .then(_ => console.log('works'),
          err => console.log('err: ', err));
```

or expand the code for `Promise.prototype.catch` into a `then` call:

```
this.afDb.list('/demo').push({a: 'b'})
    .then(_ => console.log('works'))
    .then( null, err => console.log('err: ', err)); // catch
```